# How to give dependecies in multiproject in Gradle and what is the structure?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a multi project to be built using Gradle which has a java Project and it'll be dependancy for web Project. When I build with eclipse i have given depencies of javaProj and webProj to webprojectEAR and it works(after deployed).

.ear file needs to be created using single build run whcih has the following content.

```
- lib
    javaProj.jar
- META-INF
- webProj.war
```

my project structure as follows

```
- javaProj
     build.gradle
- webProj
     build.gradle
- webProjEAR
     build.gradle
- settings.gradle
```

I'm trying to run the webProjEAR/build.gradle file and given as dependency as follows in it.

```
project(':webProjEAR') {
    dependencies { 
         compile project(':javaProj')
         compile project(':webProj')
    }
}
```

it failed with error "Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'webProjEAR:testRuntime' .when I run build files separatly I am able to create jar and war files.

Please can anyone help me how dependencies should be mentioned in the build files. And, where are the madatory locations to have a build.gradle file.

=== More Information added to the original question from here ===

My build files are as below. I have made the changes Igor Popov had mentioned.

```
// javaProj/build.gradle

apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
flatDir { dirs "../local-repo" }                        
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDir "$projectDir/src"           
        resources.srcDir "$projectDir/XML"      
    }
}

jar {
    from ('classes/com/nyl/xsl') { 
        into 'com/nyl/xsl'      
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'slf4j-api' , name: 'slf4j-api' , version: '1.5.6'
    compile group: 'slf4j-jdk14' , name: 'slf4j-jdk14' , version: '1.5.6'   
    compile group: 'com.ibm.xml.thinclient_1.0.0' , name: 'com.ibm.xml.thinclient_1.0.0' , version: '1.0.0'
    compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile group: 'saxon9' , name: 'saxon9'
    compile group: 'saxon9-dom' , name: 'saxon9-dom'
    compile group: 'xmlunit' , name: 'xmlunit' , version: '1.4'
}

==============================================

// webProj/build.gradle

apply plugin: 'war'

repositories {
    flatDir { dirs "../local-repo" }                    
}

webAppDirName = 'WebContent'                

dependencies {
    providedCompile group: 'com.ibm.xml' , name: 'com.ibm.xml' 
    providedCompile group: 'com.ibm.ws.prereq.xdi2' , name: 'com.ibm.ws.prereq.xdi2' 
    providedCompile group: 'com.ibm.ws.xml.admin.metadata' , name: 'com.ibm.ws.xml.admin.metadata' 
    providedCompile group: 'guava' , name: 'guava' , version: '11.0.2'
    providedCompile group: 'j2ee' , name: 'j2ee'    
    providedCompile group: 'slf4j-api' , name: 'slf4j-api' , version: '1.5.6'
    providedCompile group: 'slf4j-log4j12' , name: 'slf4j-log4j12' , version: '1.5.6'   
}

====================================================

// webProjEAR/build.gradle

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'ear'

repositories {
    flatDir { dirs "../local-repo" }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':javaProj')
compile project(':webProj')
}

ear {
    appDirName 'src/main/app' 
    libDirName 'APP-INF/lib' 

    from ('../javaProj/build/libs') {
        into 'lib'
    }       
    from ('../webProj/build/libs') {
        into '/'
    }
}
```

I would like to know what should contain in the  roojProj/build.gradle file. Also like to know anything needs to be changed in the above files. Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I'm trying to run the webProjEAR/build.gradle file"? What *exactly* are you doing to get the "could not resolve ..." error?

Comment: I have changed the structure as follows. (as Igor Popov had sugessted)

    rootProj
     - javaProj
        build.gradle
     - webProj
        build.gradle
     - webProjEAR
        build.gradle
     - settings.gradle
     - build.gradle

And need to create the .ear file using a single gradle run command. javaProj needs to create .jar and webProj needs to create a .war and both will be dependancy to webProjEAR. Please let me how this can be done and what are the mandory commands in each build.gradle files.

Answer (score 2):

The overall structure should be something like:

```
rootProj
  javaProj
    build.gradle
  webProj
    build.gradle
  webProjEAR
    build.gradle

  settings.gradle
  build.gradle
```

The `settings.gradle` file should contain:

```
include 'javaProj', 'webProj', 'webProjEAR'
```

For the `webProjEAR/build.gradle` you can remove the `project(':webProjEAR')`. So it should look like:

```
dependencies { 
  compile project(':javaProj')
  compile project(':webProj')
}
```

To fix the error you get, you should also post all your dependencies for `webProjEAR` (if you have others that you didn't include).

Comment: Thank you very much Igor Popov for the answer and quick responce. I have added the build files into the original question. Also want to know what should be contained in rootProj/build.gradle file. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Igor Popov, Could you please help me with this to resolve? Thank you!

Comment: @DLP: regarding the `rootProj/build.gradle` you often need it for example when adding new plugins to the build script classpath, but this doesn't seem to be your case, so you can get away without it.